# Optimised solution for function that takes a list of integers and returns the smallest positive integer that is not present in the list

Tags: list, kotlin, dataset

I'm trying to implement a function that takes a list of integers and returns the smallest positive integer that is not present in the list. For example, given the list [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

```kotlin
fun smallestMissingPositiveInteger(inputList: List<Int>): Int {
    val sortedList = inputList.filter { it > 0 }.sorted()
    var smallestMissing = 1
    
    for (i in sortedList) {
        if (i == smallestMissing) {
            smallestMissing++
        } else if (i > smallestMissing) {
            return smallestMissing
        }
    }
    
    return smallestMissing
}
```

This code seems to work for most cases, but I'm concerned about its performance when dealing with large input lists. Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem in Kotlin?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your task. Ignore my original comment.

Comment: You could add each element of the list to a `BitSet`, and then at the end call `nextClearBit()`. I believe this will be _O(N)_ instead of your _O(N log N)_.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the input is not already sorted, we could just find the difference between the input and an IntRange with the same size as the list. Filtering only the missing elements would normally be cheaper than filtering the whole list as well (read the last paragraph for this). Then we can get the smallest number from the filtered list.

```kotlin
fun Collection<Int>.smallestMissingPositiveInteger() = ((1..size) - toSet()).filter { it > 0 }.minOrNull()
```

As for performance, I'm assuming that you meant that you want less CPU time, just by "gut" alone, this one should be similar if not better than the given solution, since sorting is usually expensive, and a "minus" on a set should be quite efficient.

---

But if memory is a concern and we don't want to create a range of the same size as the list, we could store only the missing elements, filter the non positive integers and then select the smallest of them.

```kotlin
fun Collection<Int>.smallestMissingPositiveInteger(): Int? {
    val filteredSet = filter { it >= 0 }.toSet()
    val missing = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    
    var current = 1
    
    while (current != filteredSet.size) {
        if (current !in filteredSet) missing += current
        current++
    }
    
    return missing.minOrNull() //don't know what you want the return to be if none is missing, I'm assuming null
}
```

---

Btw, I don't know what you want the return to be if no element is missing, I'm assuming null. In the example you provided it returns `1`. If that is really what is desired then you can do this at the end:

`minOrNull() ?: 1`

Also, what is more eficient, filtering at first or at the end, depends on how many elements will be missing in the input and also on how many non-positive integers the list contains. I don't know what your actual data looks like.

Comment: To save an iteration, you might be able to use `firstOrNull()` instead of `minOrNull()` since the minus operation preserves order. However, the documentation doesn't specifically promise that--it's only sort of implied by the fact that a List is returned.

Comment: @Tenfour04 that would work in the sorted case, but both ways that I show are not sorted.

Comment: The first way you show is sorted because you start with a range.

Comment: oh yes, I missed that entirely...

Answer (score -1):

```
val result = input
  .asSequence()
  .filter { it > 0 }
  .distinct()
  .sorted()
  .withIndex()
  .takeWhile { (index, i) -> index + 1 == i }
  .last()
  .value + 1
```